# PHP - Best way to pagination

Tags: php, html, pagination, request

I am using this method for pagination:

I have a main holder and inside, I wrote:

```
$pag = $_REQUEST['pag'];

switch($pag) {
case 'register':
    include "inc/register.php";
    break;        
case 'noticia':
include "inc/login.php";
    break;
default:
    include "inc/main.php";
    }
```

How do professionals make this kind of dynamic pagination? How could I improve this?

Comment: Have a look at the MVC-Pattern and frameworks like CakePHP or Symphony.

Comment: That's not pagination, but "dispatching" (or "routing").